# Highcharts - Line disappears when using logarithmic axis

Tags: highcharts, axis, logarithm

If I change the y-axis type to logarithmic on the [meteogram example of the highcharts demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-meteogram#http://www.yr.no/place/United_Kingdom/England/London/forecast_hour_by_hour.xml), the temperature line stops being visible. Is this a bug or is there something in the code preventing it from displaying when in logarithmic mode?

The only change I made to the demo was to add `type: 'logarithmic'` on line 492:

```
yAxis: [{ // temperature axis
        type: 'logarithmic',
```

See [**this jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xm58tjju/).

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this is a (solvable and unknown?) bug indeed.

**Somehow a logarithmic y-axis is not compatible with a `negativeColor` attribute.**

Go to `line 594` of your [meteogram example](http://jsfiddle.net/xm58tjju/) and remove the `negativeColor: '#48AFE8'` attribute:

```
592|  zIndex: 1,
593|  color: '#FF3333',
594|  negativeColor: '#48AFE8'     << remove this line
```

Now the logarithmic plot will work as expected. [**See DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/uxkrz0dw/).

I have also set the y-axis `min`, `max` properties and both `startOnTick` and `endOnTick` to `false` to make the graph look a bit better. I hope this helps you out :)

---

**Update 1**: This bug [**has now been reported to GitHub**](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/4221)

**Update 2:** Highcharts developers have solved this bug as of **June 3, 2015** in commit [fde07c2](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/commit/fde07c24e05ff200bf2c2ea28915e47569ada6b8)

---

Comment: @user4931793 You are welcome :) We can notify the authors of highcharts about this bug if you want?